Is the elevator chord included in the calculation of the volume ratio?
I'm a little bit confused, when designing the elevator and rudder, are they included in the calculation of the volume ratio of the tail?
What I mean is after calculating the vertical and horizontal stabilizer size, to determine the control surfaces size I can use the guidelines in the photo, for example if the airplane is GA single and the horizontal stabilizer chord is 20 cm, then Ce=0.45xC=9 cm.
My question is the 9cm of the elevator added to the 20 cm of the tail to have a chord of 29cm, or the elevator chord will be 9cm of the 20cm of the horizontal stabilizer's chord?


Yes, the area of rudders and elevators are included in tail volume coefficient calculations and in your example, the 9cm will be part of 20cm chord. Rudders and elevators contribute to stability as well as control.

That picture is taken from "Aircraft Design: A Conceptual Approach" by "Daniel P. Raymer".
In the text it is clearly stated that those values are in fraction of the whole "tail chord". That means that if from the volume method you get a chord of 1m for your GA airplane then its elevator is going to use the last 45cm of that 1m horizontal tail. You can compare those preliminary values with a real Cessna 172 for example.
